# Is it OK to have a C++ class with lots (lots!) of boolean fields?

Tags: c++, structure, icc

I have a C++ class with lots of `bool` fields indicating different aspects of a system. This class is part of another class that gets copied (a lot!).

My questions:

- Is it OK to have the class with lots of bools? Or should I manually compact it into larger data types?
- Given that the class gets copied a lot, is there any benefit in defining my own copy/move constructors?
- Or should I just leave it alone and let the compiler optimize this?

Comment: Write in the clearest possible way, and optimize when you find a bottleneck.

Comment: std::vector<bool> is specially optimized for such case

Comment: @Slava I'd preferably advise [`std::bitset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) vs [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, generally it is OK, assuming that your class is not used to instantiate a huge number of objects. In the latter case using the whole `bool` to represent a boolean flag might prove to be too wasteful. But your are talking about flags that represent "different aspects of a system", which sounds like something that does not produce massive amounts of instances.

Secondly, maybe you should consider converting these fields into a `bool` array indexed by a enum. For example, instead of a

```
bool has_printer;
bool needs_optimizations;
```

use

```
enum {
  OPT_HAS_PRINTER,
  OPT_NEEDS_OPTIMIZATION,

  OPT_COUNT_
};

bool options[OPT_COUNT_];
```

This will make your collection of fields "run-time iteratable", which might simplify a lot of processing code that doesn't care about application-specific meaning of each field (like copying code, reading-writing code etc.).

Comment: A `std::vector<bool>` would be much better than an array, as it does (implementation-specific, but in most cases) the bitfield optimization for you.

Comment: @aruisdante: I don't see any benefit in converting this into bit-fields for a singleton-like object. Bit-fields are a low-level feature whose purpose is achieving maximum memory savings at the expense of performance. One should use bit-fields only when one really has to.

Comment: But the OP says it's not a singleton, it's being copied. Repeatedly. For an actual signleton you could make an argument for an array of bools, but even then doing enum-based bitmasks would probably still be much more efficient. Your construction is simply ``||``'ing the bitmasks together, and then reading them is just ``&&``'ing.

Comment: It's all theoretical until you profile. There may be cases where `bool[N]` is too big, `std::bitset<N>` too inefficient and `char[N]` just the right compromise between space overhead and time overhead _for the particular access pattern of this program_. We can't predict that up front.